# I found the reason for the mistake but I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python

There is no A2 data in the 'wb' table，that is, data from '客户代码', so report this error.

I'm working on XLSX tables, analyzing the data, and redistributing the stored data according to the sample.According to the analysis of sample tables, the tables processed now have no sample data. In this case, I do not deal with them, but only store the existing data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import openpyxl 

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('康之源药业.xlsx')
s1 = wb.active

def getdata(filename):
    data = []
    for col in s1.columns:
        '''取出每一列的值'''
        line = [cell.value for cell in col if cell.value != None]
        data.append(line)
    return data


def cachedata(data):
    '''数据储存'''
    for i in data:
        '''为空的列表不处理'''
        if len(i) != 0:
            #data.remove(i)
            if i[0] == '销售时间':
                a0 = i
            if i[0] == '生产厂家':
                a1 = i
            if i[0] == '客户代码':
                a2 = i 
            if i[0] == '客户名称':
                a3 = i
            if i[0] == '产品代码':
                a4 = i
            if i[0] == '产品名称':
                a5 = i
            if i[0] == '产品规格':
                a6 = i
            if i[0] == '单位':
                a7 = i
            if i[0] == '批号':
                a8 = i
            if i[0] == '数量':
                a9 = i
            if i[0] == '含税单价':
                a10 = i
            if i[0] == '商品名称':
                a11 = i
            if i[0] == '不含税单价':
                a12 = i
            if i[0] == '含税金额':
                a13 = i
            if i[0] == '不含税金额':
                a14 = i
            if i[0] == '出货类型':
                a15 = i
            if i[0] == '客户城市':
                a16 = i
            if i[0] == '客户地址':
                a17 = i
            if i[0] == '经销商发货单号':
                a18 = i
            if i[0] == '出货仓库':
                a19 = i
            if i[0] == '购进单位编码':
                a20 = i
            if i[0] == '一级商编码':
                a21 = i
            if i[0] == '一级商名称':
                a22 = i
    return a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20,a21,a22

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = getdata(wb)
    cachedata = cachedata(data)
    a2 = cachedata[2]
    print(a2)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yang\Desktop\3.py", line 107, in <module>
    cachedata = cachedata(data)
  File "C:\Users\Yang\Desktop\3.py", line 76, in cachedata
    return a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20,a21,a22
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a2' referenced before assignment
```

But when I add in the `a2` data, the code works.

Comment: You can use ternary operator, i.e. `a0 = i if i[0] == '销售时间' else None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a default value for your variables in `cachedata` so that they still exist, whether or not they were allocated a value:

```
def cachedata(data):
    a0 = a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = a5 = a6 = a7 = a8 = a9 = a10 = a11 = a12 = a13 = a14 = \
    a15 = a16 = a17 = a18 = a19 = a20 = a21 = a22 = []
    '''数据储存'''
    for i in data:
        '''为空的列表不处理'''
        if len(i) != 0:
            #data.remove(i)
            if i[0] == '销售时间':
                a0 = i
            if i[0] == '生产厂家':
                a1 = i
            if i[0] == '客户代码':
                a2 = i 
            if i[0] == '客户名称':
                a3 = i
            if i[0] == '产品代码':
                a4 = i
            if i[0] == '产品名称':
                a5 = i
            if i[0] == '产品规格':
                a6 = i
            if i[0] == '单位':
                a7 = i
            if i[0] == '批号':
                a8 = i
            if i[0] == '数量':
                a9 = i
            if i[0] == '含税单价':
                a10 = i
            if i[0] == '商品名称':
                a11 = i
            if i[0] == '不含税单价':
                a12 = i
            if i[0] == '含税金额':
                a13 = i
            if i[0] == '不含税金额':
                a14 = i
            if i[0] == '出货类型':
                a15 = i
            if i[0] == '客户城市':
                a16 = i
            if i[0] == '客户地址':
                a17 = i
            if i[0] == '经销商发货单号':
                a18 = i
            if i[0] == '出货仓库':
                a19 = i
            if i[0] == '购进单位编码':
                a20 = i
            if i[0] == '一级商编码':
                a21 = i
            if i[0] == '一级商名称':
                a22 = i
    return a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a17,a18,a19,a20,a21,a22
```

Comment: thx,I've created variables before, but with the'for'loop.But I still received the error.

```
for i, s in enumerate(range(23)):
 '''循环创建变量'''
 locals()['a'+str(i)] = []

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this way:

```py
def cachedata(data):
    '''数据储存'''
    for i in data:
        '''为空的列表不处理'''
        if len(i) != 0:
            #data.remove(i)
            if i[0] == '销售时间':
                a0 = i
            if i[0] == '生产厂家':
                a1 = i
            if i[0] == '客户代码':
                a2 = i 
            if i[0] == '客户名称':
                a3 = i
            if i[0] == '产品代码':
                a4 = i
            if i[0] == '产品名称':
                a5 = i
            if i[0] == '产品规格':
                a6 = i
            if i[0] == '单位':
                a7 = i
            if i[0] == '批号':
                a8 = i
            if i[0] == '数量':
                a9 = i
            if i[0] == '含税单价':
                a10 = i
            if i[0] == '商品名称':
                a11 = i
            if i[0] == '不含税单价':
                a12 = i
            if i[0] == '含税金额':
                a13 = i
            if i[0] == '不含税金额':
                a14 = i
            if i[0] == '出货类型':
                a15 = i
            if i[0] == '客户城市':
                a16 = i
            if i[0] == '客户地址':
                a17 = i
            if i[0] == '经销商发货单号':
                a18 = i
            if i[0] == '出货仓库':
                a19 = i
            if i[0] == '购进单位编码':
                a20 = i
            if i[0] == '一级商编码':
                a21 = i
            if i[0] == '一级商名称':
                a22 = i
    local_ref = locals()
    return tuple(local_ref.get(a + str(i), []) for i in range(23))
```

Comment: 'return'only creates variables, but does not perform'if' data analysis operations. So variables should be created before analysis.

Comment: @jasonyang my method can return a0 ~ a22. For example,  if you have not  created `a2`, it will return default `[]`. In python, we return multi value by tuple.